# Merge replication error

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I have a configuration problem to create a Merge/Pull replication between two databases SQLServer 2012. I have an error while creating subscription : **Subscriptions for the following Subscribers cannot be initialized immediately because the snapshot is not available**

Image : http://s22.postimg.org/vl1ww6z2p/error.png

How solve it ?

Comment: Does the snapshot exist, and can it be accessed from the subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the initial snapshot.  Right-click the publication under the **Local Publications** folder and click **View Snapshot Agent Status**.  Then click Start.  Once the snapshot is generated, synchronize your subscription to apply the snapshot.

This is covered in [Create and Apply the Initial Snapshot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151788.aspx).